# Как задать программе автоматический подбор размера окна в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Пишу пробную программу на `Python` с помощью `GUI Tkinter`. В программе есть окна для ввода данных, вот только есть маленькая проблемка. Точнее не проблемка, а небольшое неудобство - таким окна приходится задавать размер вручную. Постоянно подбирать его неудобно, поэтому хотелось чтобы `Tkinter` или специальный скрипт просчитывал допустимый размер этого окна. Возможно ли такое сделать? Пример, в котором не указывается `.geometry` не подходит, т.к. получается такая ерунда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: заменить tkinter на kivy. там с авторазмерами всё норм

Comment: @Интик, это выход из ситуации, а мне нужно решение

Comment: @Интик kivy — отстой! Надо PyQt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам нашёл решение проблемы. Оказывается я чуток неправильно размещал кнопку "Сохранить". Я размещал элементы через `grid`, но т.к. у меня не выходило разместить кнопку в правом нижнем углу, то я использовал параметр `padx`, который делал отступы как справа, так и слева. Из-за этого неправильно автоматически подбирался размер окна.